# How to solve this inequality?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

solve for the smallest N value for this inequality, I tried several online calculators and they are not working.

[image]

Comment: Is this a question about Mathematica or about Mathematics?

Comment: No, this is not a "get someone to do your homework" site...

Comment: `NestWhile[# + 1 &, 0, NIntegrate[(x^2 + 4)^4/2^x, {x, #, # + 1}] > 1 &]` . Notice, I use NIntegrate , so it may occur some precision problem.

Comment: `Reduce[Integrate[(x^2 + 4)^4/2^x, {x, n, n + 1}] < 1/10, n]` Or if you want to search for it, you could start your search at this value: `Reduce[(x^2 + 4)^4/2^x < 1/10 /. x -> n + 1, n]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: That does not work for `Integrate[(x^2 + 4)^Pi/2^x, {x, n, n + 1}]`.

Comment: I apologize to all future users for whom `(x^2 + 4)^Pi/2^x` is their favorite function.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  You suggestion does not work if `Integrate[f[x], {x, n, n + 1}]` cannot be expressed in a closed form. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 `f[x]` is undefined.   Why all this childish caviling?

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
f[n_] := NIntegrate[(x^2 + 4)^4/2^x, {x, n, n + 1}]
```

though the above integral can be expressed in a closed form.
First, the result of

```
NMinimize[{f[n], n <= 10}, n, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{244.597, {n -> -0.120219}}`

kicks out `n<=10`. Second, we find

```
NMinimize[{n, f[n] <= 0.1 && n >= 10}, n, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{47.5369, {n -> 47.5369}}`

The command

```
Plot[{Evaluate[f[n]], 0.1}, {n, 40, 60}]
```

[image]

confirms it. Just to compare

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 0, NIntegrate[(x^2 + 4)^4/2^x, {x, #, # + 1}] > 0.1 &]
```

> `48`

Comment: `NestWhile[# + 0.01 &, 1, 
  NIntegrate[(x^2 + 4)^4/2^x, {x, #, # + 1}] > 
    0.1 &] // AbsoluteTiming` results in `{34.8565, 47.54}`.

Answer (score 1):

We set `t=1/N` and use `NDSolve`.

```
f[x_] := (x^2 +4)^4/2^x; 
NDSolve[{F'[t] == (f[1/t + 1] - f[1/t]) (-1/t^2), 
  F[1] == Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, 2}], 
  WhenEvent[F[t] <= 1/10, Print[Ceiling[1/t]]]}, F, {t, 1/1000, 1}]
```

> `48`

```
i[n_] = Integrate[f[x], {x, n, n + 1}];
{i[47], i[48], i[49]} // N
```

> `{0.132621, 0.0783269, 0.0461038}`

Comment: `g[x_] := (x^2 + 4)^\[Pi]/
  2^x; NDSolve[{G'[t] == (g[1/t + 1] - g[1/t]) (-1/t^2), 
  G[1] == NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 1, 2}], 
  WhenEvent[G[t] <= 1/10, Print[Ceiling[1/t]]]}, G, {t, 1/100, 1}]`  for π .